# Pass method from controller as callback to another

Tags: php, yii

I have something like this:

```
public function generateAudio(){

$sourceProcessor = new Sourceprocessor($_SESSION['input_file']);
$sourceProcessor->extractAudio();

}

public function checkProgress($percent){
  //do something with a percents
}
```

and in `SourceProcessor` I have something like this:

```
public function extractAudio($callback=NULL, $folder=NULL){

   if(is_callable($callback)){
       $callback($percentage);
   }

}
```

I tried to pass method like

```
$sourceProcessor->extractAudio(array($this,'checkProgress');
$sourceProcessor->extractAudio(array($this->checkProgress());
```

but nothing seems to work. Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your method like this:

```
$sourceProcessor->extractAudio(array($this,'checkProgress'));
```

And call the callback from `extractAudio` like this:

```
call_user_func($callback, $percent);
```

See the manual entry for [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more information